# Action Cam as100 and 2.0.0 API

Tags: android, camera, sony, sony-camera-api

I own the as100 and have downloaded the API version 2.0.0. Does this API allow for this hardware:

1. list the content of the images/videos?
2. download a particular image/video?

In the Android demo app (CameraRemoteSampleApp) from the download that I have running,  there is a function called findActionListUrl(). I add some print statements and get the following 3 items: 'guide', 'accessControl', and 'camera'. The Sony_CameraRemoteAPIbeta_API-Reference_v2.00.pdf and Sony_CameraRemoteAPIbeta_DevelopmentGuide_v1.20.pdf makes no reference of 'guide' and 'accessControl'. However 1 of the pdf files make mention of avContent but the function doesn't return that value. Why is that?

Another question: was Play Memories Mobile created using the Sony_CameraRemote API?

Thanks,Jim

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately the AS100 does not support listing or downloading images/video.  Only the newer AS200 supports those.  That is why you aren't seeing "avContent" returned as a service.  "guide" is mentioned on page 13 of Sony_CameraRemoteAPIbeta_DevelopmentGuide_v1.20.pdf and is used to get a list of supported API services.  "accessControl" cannot be used via the Camera Remote API.

Play Memories is created using a superset of the API and may contain functionality not available to the API.

Comment: Thanks for the info Marlin.When I call getAvailableApiList it does list out "setCameraFunction" as one of its options. And if I'm reading the API reference v2.0.0 pdf file correct, one of its options is "Contents Transfer". Can you provide a small Java method that allows me to call getAvailableCameraFunction and getSupportedCameraFunction? Also are there plans to update the firmware of AS100 with those capabilities? Also my page 13 doesn't have a reference to "guide" as i'm reading the v2.0.0 of that pdf.